# Wordpress "freeze" homepage?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site for a client. The site has a custom homepage. Every Saturday my client populates the homepage with new content, so old content gets removed and new content takes over. So the homepage gets updated once a week only.

Now, my client wants to be able to gradually populate the page with new content during the week and preview the changes (without regular visitors seeing the updated content) and schedule the homepage to be updated with the new content on Saturday for everyone to see.

Is there any way, after the homepage gets re-populated with new content on Saturday, to kind of "freeze" the page and serve static HTML to regular visitors, while logged-in users like my client will be able to see the dynamic version of the page and preview the changes they make to it they make during the week. And then the following Saturday to automatically "refresh" the page with the new content, and "freeze" it again?

Staging/version control environment would probably be an overkill here because it's just for one page (the homepage) and also because I don't think my client, a non-technical person, can manage staging that well. Caching plugins would probably not work either because, as I understand, if the users clear the cache in their browser it will show all the new content which they are not expected to see...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you can save posts and pages as drafts.

Comment: But I need the homepage to be always live, not in draft version.

Comment: Why don't you just tell the client to have a draft home page?  The client can preview the draft, and copy and past to the real home page when desired.

Comment: @bozdoz - a better option would be `future` and not `draft` . this will also  schedule the post to become published on a certain date like the OP wanted . @ninusik - you cn use the `future`post with conditionalstatements in multiple loops to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice, but as I understand your advice for Draft and Future applies for regular posts (with copy/paste content) - my homepage is a few custom loops, so it's not really a simple cut/paste, it cannot be simply edited via Post Edit screen.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). So on your home page template, you will first see if the visitor is loggged-in or not. If they're logged-in, you display the actual content of the home page. If they are not, you get the transient( [`get_transient()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient) ) and if it's still active(it doesn't return a `false`), you display it. If it returnse `false`, you do `ob_start()`, display the actual contents for the home page, then do `$contents = ob_get_clean();`, update your transient with [`set_transient()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient) and `echo $contents;`.

In addition to that you can add an action to the `init`, `template_redirect` or any other hook you like(as long as it fires on every page load). There you will have to check if it's time to display the new content of the home page. If it is, you use [`delete_transient()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient) to delete the transient, so your home page will update.

I don't have time to give you a code example right now, but I think you should be able to figure-out the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it! It might be a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "Future" post status ..

WordPress has the ability to "schedule" posts .
So you tell your client to "schedule" publish the post to the one day he wants , during all the week as he goes .

then, you have MANY ways to make sure only ONE group can see them for example, admins - by using some [conditions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)  like :

```
if (is_admin()) {

}
```

now , as I said, here are many many ways to achieve that , by filtering the query, add a new query , add [multiple loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_1) etc , etc .

for example :

```
  if (is_admin()) { // if we are admin - or any other conditional wanted
// start a new query
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_status=future');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
//do the thing
wp_reset_postdata();
// start the normal query ...
    }
```

Another way would be to use 
[get_post_status()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) normally inside the loop

```
$status = get_post_status();

if ($status == 'future') && (is_admin()) {
//display post as you would
} 
// continue normal query / post display here ..
```

so this way , the page would function normally for "normal" users - until the update date , but will show the schedualed posts for the admins (or logged in , or specific user , or whatever condition you want)

**UPDATE I :** Proof of concept as per comments :

warning : ugly non efficient code. concept demonstration..

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
// start here 

                    $future_q = new WP_Query( 'post_status=future' );

                    while ( $future_q->have_posts() ) : $future_q->the_post();
                    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' ) == TRUE ){
                    the_title();}
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    echo 'Normal start here :';
                    the_title();
```

The above code works for my settings.
True , it is ugly code , it is not eficient , it is not the best way , but it is a PROOF OF CONCEPT for the possible use of `future`post status to do exactly what the OP has asked .
You can put this concept to action with multiple loops , by modifying and filtering query vars , by altering loops or by checking for loop status INSIDE the loop or even with get_posts() - all that with any condition that you want .

Comment: `is_admin()` checks whether we're viewing a Dashboard(in other words, admin) page. The correct way to check would be `current_user_can( 'administrator' )`. Also don't forget that normal visitors should still be able to see the content of the page. If you set it to "future", then they will not be able to see the page, or if they do, they will see the content of the page(since you don't have two contents - for the "future" post and the current state of the post).

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov - Normal visitors will be able to see the page, because if you will read my answer carefully (not just the code)  - the idea is to use multiple queries / loops . one for those who can see and one for those who can not . second - the `is_admin()`will work as long as an admin is logged in (with the top bar...) - but also this , if you will read my answer , is just an example to any other possible wp conditional statements...

Comment: [`is_admin() - Codex Page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin), [`is_admin() - in source`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/load.php#L585), [`WP_ADMIN - constant definition`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/_constants/WP_ADMIN.html). Please explain how this function will return true if you're an administrator(or if the top bar is displayed). Also yes - I did read your answer carefully. Please explain further how you will have the old content and the new content displayed accordingly.

Comment: From what I understood you suggest to have one post with status 'future'. What the author of the question is looking for is to have two states of one page - default(cached, or `freezed` as he refferes to) state - visible to normal visitors, updated every Saturday and actual state - the actual contents of the page, visible only to administrators, or everyone else after Saturday.

Comment: see my update . paste the code . check. think also of normal loop that will display posts regularly , but will also grab and check the `future` post status and will display it with conditional statements only to admins / whatever...

Comment: Ok, I do understand your idea now and it's an option yes. Still my first comment is valid saying that `is_admin()` is **not** a conditional statement for whether the current user is admin or not.

Comment: @Obmerk Kronen: thanks, it could be a good solution for regular posts, but my homepage is not a regular post, it doesn't have regular text content to be copied/pasted. It consists of a few custom WP loops and it cannot be edited or scheduled through the Post Edit screen.

Comment: @ninusik - every content (even pages) or custom post types can be scheduled , and the fact that you have multiple loops just suggest that it will be an even easier concept to implement .  I see so many overkill solutions for simple problems, that it won´t be the first . Many people forget the simple built in solutions that WordPress offers from the beginning . Seen that with Custom_fields, then custom post types and taxonomies , and now I guess it´s the Transients API´s turn. But hey - what ever solution is better for you is the best ..

Comment: @Obmerk Kronen: Thank you for your advice. Believe me, I am also a fan of simple and elegant solutions and try to avoid unnecessary overkill. I guess I didn't give default WP scheduling enough thought, I assumed it was for "regular" posts and pages with content in the WYSIWYG editor. Content on my homepage is all dynamic PHP code in the page template. So I will explore your suggestion further. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the plenty of comments, but I think that the Transients API will give a considerable advantage - it will spare processing time - simply because you will have to generate the content for normal visitors once a week(considering that it's multiple loops and dynamic PHP and not just `the_title()`, `the_content()` + some HTML, then it could have some impact) - if the site is getting a lot of visits, this could mean that you will decrease the execution of the script that generates the home page content a **lot**. Still @ninusik - I hope you figure-out how to best implement this :)

Comment: Thank you both for your input. @Nikola Ivanov Nikolov, actually Transients was suggested to me by another source too, and I do think that would be the best solution in my case, especially considering the loops and other complexities of the homepage and the site (which were necessary complexities, not an overkill). But Obmerk Kronen's solution sounds curious and I'll explore it more, I'll keep it in mind for use, maybe not in this case, but for the future. Thank you both!